# How to write output in parquet fileformat in a MapReduce job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, parquet, file-format

I am looking to write MapReduce output in parquet fileformat using [parquet-mr](https://github.com/apache/parquet-mr/tree/master/parquet-hadoop/src/main/java/org/apache/parquet/hadoop/example) library as something like below :

```
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class); 
        job.setOutputFormatClass(ParquetOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        ParquetOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));
        ParquetOutputFormat.setCompression(job, CompressionCodecName.GZIP);


        SkipBadRecords.setMapperMaxSkipRecords(conf, Long.MAX_VALUE);
        SkipBadRecords.setAttemptsToStartSkipping(conf, 0);

        job.submit();
```

However, I keep getting errors like these :

```
2018-02-23 09:32:58,325 WARN [main] org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild: Exception running child : java.lang.NullPointerException: writeSupportClass should not be null
    at org.apache.parquet.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:38)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getWriteSupport(ParquetOutputFormat.java:350)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:293)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:283)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$NewTrackingRecordWriter.<init>(ReduceTask.java:548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:622)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
```

I understand that writeSupportClass needs to be passed/set as something like

```
ParquetOutputFormat.setWriteSupportClass(job, ProtoWriteSupport.class);
```

but can I ask how can specify schema,implement ProtoWriteSupport or any other WriteSupport classes out there? What methods do I need to implement and are there any examples of doing this in a correct way?

If it helps, my MR job's output should look like & stored in parquet format:

```
Text      INTWRITABLE
 a            100
```

Comment: `ParquetOutputFormat.setWriteSupportClass()` is already there.  I have added a solution.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! I am in fact looking for how to implement ProtoWriteSupport and specify schema based on my output fields in reducer <Text,IntWritable>. I have edited my question for further clarity.

Comment: I believe `ProtoWriteSupport` is already generic enough and should be usable. Updated my answer with `javadoc` link, check the nested classes section.

Comment: Thank you! This helped too - https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-4-x/topics/cdh_ig_parquet.html#parquet_mapreduce

Answer (score 0):

Try `ParquetOutputFormat.setWriteSupportClass(job, ProtoWriteSupport.class);`

```
ProtoWriteSupport<T extends MessageOrBuilder>
```

Implementation of WriteSupport for writing Protocol Buffers.

Check [Javadoc](http://www.atetric.com/atetric/javadoc/com.twitter/parquet-protobuf/1.6.0/parquet/proto/ProtoWriteSupport.html) for list of nested default classes available.

The [CDH Tutorial](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-4-x/topics/cdh_ig_parquet.html) on using parquet file format with MapReduce, Hive, HBase, and Pig.